# d3.js ticks values not working as expected

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm a d3 noob. I have a chart that looks close to what I want.
[image]

Right now the xlabels for years are all hard coded. Like this:

```
.call(d3.axisBottom(xScale)
                .ticks([1850, 1900, 1950, 2000]));
```

However I want to update the tick marks to be dynamic so labels show up every 5 years or so and I don't need to hard code those in.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
<body>
<div id="container" class="svg-container"></div>
<script>

//--------------------------PREPARATION--------------------------//
//------------------------SVG PREPARATION------------------------//
var width = 960;
var height = 500;
var margin = 5;
var padding = 5;
var adj = 20;
// we are appending SVG first
var svg = d3.select("div#container").append("svg")
.attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
//.attr("viewBox", "-20 -20 1600 1600")
.attr("viewBox", "-" + adj + " -"+ adj + " " + (width + adj) + " " + (height + adj*2))
.style("padding", padding)
.style("margin", margin)
.classed("svg-content", true);

//-----------------------SCALES PREPARATION----------------------//
var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
    .rangeRound([0, width])
    .paddingInner(0.05);
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0]);

//------------------------DATA PREPARATION-----------------------//
var dataset = d3.csv("q3.csv");
dataset.then(function(data) {
    data.map(function(d) {
            d.running_total = +d.running_total;
            return d;});
});

dataset.then(function(data) {
    xScale.domain(data.map(function(d) {return d.year}))
    yScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d)
                             {return d.running_total; })]);
});

console.log(dataset);


dataset.then(function (data) {
    svg.selectAll("div")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function(d){
        return xScale(d.year);
    })
    .attr("y", function (d) {
        return yScale(d.running_total);
    })
    .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
    .attr("height", function (d) {
        return height - yScale(d.running_total);
    });
    svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale)
            .ticks([1850, 1900, 1950, 2000]));

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));
});

</script>
</body>
```

I tried setting the ticks to how many labels I want like this: `.ticks(50)` but that didn't work (all the labels showed up)

```
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale)
            .ticks(50));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis#axis_ticks) explains your issue: `axis.ticks()` has no effect with a band scale.

> This method has no effect if the scale does not implement scale.ticks, as with **band** and point scales. (emphasis mine)

Therefore, what you can do for having one label every 5 years is filtering the scale's domain:

```
.call(d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickValues(xScale.domain().filter(function(_, i) {
  return !(i % 5);
})));
```

Comment: It is so beautiful! Thank you.